# How can I tell when GKHostedAuthenticateViewController has disappeared?

Tags: ios, authentication, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to detect when Apple's GameKit user authentication view is dismissed and gone in a Cocos2D app.  I want to show another view right after the user is authenticated, so I'm just trying to find an appropriate trigger.

Here's what I'm doing: Following Apple's Game Center programming guide, I'm checking for `[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]` and if user is not auth'd, I'm setting the authenticateHandler and saving the returned viewController like so:

```
[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil)
    {
        //save the returned view controller to show it when user tries to access leaderboards, etc.
        _savedGCAuthViewController = viewController;
    } else if([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]){
        _userAuthenticated = YES;
    }
};
```

I save the returned viewController so I can display it at a more appropriate time like this:

```
AppController *appDelegate = (AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navController presentViewController:_savedGCAuthViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That all works fine.  The problem is I have no way of knowing when that view is gone.

All of the other questions/answers I see here on StackOverflow say to subclass the viewController in a situation like this to tap into the viewDidDisappear method, but I can't subclass the view controller because Apple doesn't provide access to the headers for the GKHostedAuthenticateViewController class.

I've also dug around for any notification messages to tap into, but it doesn't look like UIViewController uses any NSNotificationCenter-style messages.

Ideas?

I'm relatively new to iOS, but is there a way to maybe tap into the view hierarchy somehow and insert my own view that gets disposed of when GKHostedAuthenticateViewController does?  Maybe as a parent viewcontroller or child?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `GKHostedAuthenticateViewController` in a controller of your own before presenting it, so you can access the viewDidDisappear/viewWillDisappear methods:

```
// Simple class to wrap GKHostedAuthenticateViewController
class AuthController: UINavigationController {

    var viewWillDisappearHandler: ((Bool) -> ())?

    convenience init(authController: UIViewController) {
        self.init(rootViewController: authController)

        self.modalInPopover = true
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
        self.navigationBarHidden = true
        self.preferredContentSize = authController.preferredContentSize
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        viewWillDisappearHandler?(animated)
    }
}
```

Then in your `GKLocalPlayer.authenticateHandler` you can set up your viewWillDisappearHandler:

```
GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticateHandler = { 
    (viewController: UIViewController?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if let viewController = viewController {
        let authController = AuthController(authController: viewController)
        authController.viewWillDisappearHandler = { (animated: Bool) -> () in
            println("viewController is disappearing")
        }
        self.presentViewController(authController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Authenticated
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the Game Center authentication view controller is an instance of `GKHostedAuthenticateViewController` which is a private class we're not allowed to use or reference. It doesn't give us any way to cleanly detect when it is dismissed (unlike instances of `GKGameCenterViewController` which allow us to via the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` protocol.

This solution (read workaround) works by testing in the background every quarter of a second for when the view controller has been dismissed. It's not pretty, but it works.

The code below should be part of your presentingViewController, which should conform to the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` protocol.

Swift and Objective-C provided.

```
// Swift
func authenticateLocalUser() {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticateHandler == nil {
        GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticateHandler = { (gameCenterViewController: UIViewController?, gameCenterError: NSError?) in
            if let gameCenterError = gameCenterError {
                log.error("Game Center Error: \(gameCenterError.localizedDescription)")
            }

            if let gameCenterViewControllerToPresent = gameCenterViewController {
                self.presentGameCenterController(gameCenterViewControllerToPresent)
            }
            else if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
                // Enable GameKit features
                log.debug("Player already authenticated")
            }
            else {
                // Disable GameKit features
                log.debug("Player not authenticated")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        log.debug("Authentication Handler already set")
    }
}

func testForGameCenterDismissal() {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.25 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        if let presentedViewController = self.presentedViewController {
            log.debug("Still presenting game center login")
            self.testForGameCenterDismissal()
        }
        else {
            log.debug("Done presenting, clean up")
            self.gameCenterViewControllerCleanUp()
        }
    }
}

func presentGameCenterController(viewController: UIViewController) {
    var testForGameCenterDismissalInBackground = true

    if let gameCenterViewController = viewController as? GKGameCenterViewController {
        gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
        testForGameCenterDismissalInBackground = false
    }

    presentViewController(viewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        if testForGameCenterDismissalInBackground {
            self.testForGameCenterDismissal()
        }
    }
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {
    gameCenterViewControllerCleanUp()
}

func gameCenterViewControllerCleanUp() {
    // Do whatever needs to be done here, resume game etc
}
```

Note: the log.error and log.debug calls are referencing XCGLogger: https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger

```
// Objective-C
- (void)authenticateLocalUser
{
    GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    if (!localPlayer.authenticateHandler) {
        [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError* error) {
            if (error) {
                DLog(@"Game Center Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            if (viewcontroller) {
                [weakSelf presentGameCenterController:viewcontroller];
            }
            else if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]) {
                // Enable GameKit features
                DLog(@"Player already authenticated");
            }
            else {
                // Disable GameKit features
                DLog(@"Player not authenticated");
            }
        })];
    }
    else {
        DLog(@"Authentication Handler already set");
    }
}

- (void)testForGameCenterDismissal
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        if (self.presentedViewController) {
            DLog(@"Still presenting game center login");
            [self testForGameCenterDismissal];
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"Done presenting, clean up");
            [self gameCenterViewControllerCleanUp];
        }
    });
}

- (void)presentGameCenterController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    BOOL testForGameCenterDismissalInBackground = YES;
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[GKGameCenterViewController class]]) {
        [(GKGameCenterViewController*)viewController setGameCenterDelegate:self];
        testForGameCenterDismissalInBackground = NO;
    }

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{
        if (testForGameCenterDismissalInBackground) {
            [self testForGameCenterDismissal];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*)gameCenterViewController
{
    [self gameCenterViewControllerCleanUp];
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerCleanUp
{
    // Do whatever needs to be done here, resume game etc
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Post your own `NSNotification` from the `authenticateHandler` to indicate that it has finished. Your presenting view controller should listen for this notification.

Comment: This won't work. The authentication handler finishes when it passes the `GKHostedAuthenticateViewController` to you, that's when you present it, not when the user finishes logging in.